# When click reverse an Array React

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an array, and when I first click on a button the collection is reverse. 
But if I click once again, the collection return at the initial order.

Do you any idea for prevent this thing ?

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
 arr.reverse();
  console.log(arr)
})
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a flag, and reverse the array only if the flag is `false`:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
let reversedFlag = false;

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (!reversedFlag) {
    arr.reverse();
    reversedFlag = true;
  }

  console.log(arr)
})
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

one way to slove the issue is to move your array inside your function

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
 arr.reverse();
  console.log(arr)
})
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: This will unnecessarily reverse a _new_ array on _every single click_. This is potentially both CPU and memory heavy.

Comment: @Xufox its true that it will reverse a new array on every single click but when it come to CPU and memory heavy you're wrong cause it's not https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-memory-management-how-to-handle-4-common-memory-leaks-3f28b94cfbec

Comment: There is an array reversal process for every click. How does this not affect the CPU? As for memory usage: again, _potentially_ — it’s unknown how the code uses the reversed array. For one, a new array is _created_ every time, which affects memory. I’m not talking about memory leaks, necessarily.

Comment: @Xufox  "There is an array reversal process for every click. How does this not affect the CPU" : and this is what the OP is asking for (I wasn't thinking about memory leak either)

Comment: The OP isn’t asking about reversing a new array on every click, they’re asking about _preventing_ a new reversal of the same array.